# Deploy a solution package from command prompt

Tags: wss-3.0, visual-studio, deployment, vsewss

We are trying to automate the solution deployment to a test environment. We are using vsewss 1.3.

To do this we are trying to run the following command from the visual studio command prompt:

```
devenv xxx.sln /deploy Release /package
```

When we do this we get the following error:

```
specified method is not supported
```

And a message that the deployment has been skipped.

Anyone have an idea what the problem could be, or how to fix it.

**EDIT**

I have tried a few things:

- Gave "Everyone" group modify access to the area where the solution files are
- Checked out solution and projects files so they are not readonly
- Closed VS to avoid read/write locks
- Have managed to get a more detailed error message:

  System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
     at EnvDTE.Project.get_CodeModel()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Reflection.TypeFinder.GetTypesAsCodeElement(Project project, CodeElement parent, String targetTypeFullName)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Reflection.TypeFinder.Find(Project project, String targetTypeFullName)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.FindClasses(Project project)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.GetClassMap(Project project)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.Constract()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureDirector.GetFeatureElement(ICollection`1 directors)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureDirector.Constract()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceSolutionDirector.ConstractElements()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceSolutionDirector.Constract()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SolutionCreator.CreateCore(ISPProject project, IDirectorCreator creator)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SolutionCreator.Create(ISPProject project)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Forms.SPToolWindow.CreateSolutions()

Comment: Maybe you should post a link to some reference where it states that the command you are trying to run is supposed to work.

Comment: This is something that comes with VseWss 1.3 isn't it?

Comment: @Japp, you are right we are using VseWss 1.3, I have updated the question

Comment: Interesting, the more detaild message you posted as part of your most recent edit is the same as in http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/966/problem-installing-patterns-practices-sharepoint-guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found that we do not get this problem when we create a new project.

These projects were originally created with an earlier version of VseWss. There appears to be something in the project files that ties it to a specific version of VseWss.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have User Access Control (UAC) turned on?

Try turning it off.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/cb82e26d-a2fb-48e8-a722-2a4bb41e6c8b

Comment: This answer seems a bit unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks, I also found this article. Do you know what UAC they are refering to? I could not find where they meant that UAC should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Does the path to your .sln file have any spaces in it by any chance? If so, ensure you have it wrapped in quotes like

**"c:\my folder with paces\solution.wsp"**

Comment: @Jaap, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly it did not help. I did not have any spaces, but I did try giving the full path that I was not doing previously.